# How to get configs to the Config service in the testing context in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, configuration, zend-framework2, phpunit, configuration-files

I have a ZF2 application and want to write some integration tests for in. I'm using PHPUnit v6 (no `zend-test`). PHPUnit is set up and the `Bootstrap` class implemented. Everything is/was working.

For normal requests the framework scans the config folders (usually defined in the `config/application.config.php`: `['module_listener_options']['config_glob_paths']`) and merges all the configs for me. But now I'm in the testing context and need some configs from a custom config file (e.g. `config/autoload/module/audit-logging.local.php`) -- and cannot find out, how to add/merge them to/with the other configs.

**How to integrate configs from custom config files and make them available for the application, when running PHPUnit tests?**

Answer (score 1):

How about creating environment-specific configuration files, for example:

```
config
├── application.config.php
├── autoload
│   └── global.php
└── environment
    ├── development.php
    ├── production.php
    └── testing.php
```

and then adjusting `config/application.config.php` to this:

```
return [
    'modules' => $modules,
    'module_listener_options' => [
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
            __DIR__ . '/environment/' . (\getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production') . '.php',
        ],
        'module_paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../module',
            __DIR__ . '/../vendor',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now all you need to do is configure the `APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, and set it to `testing`, for example. Then you can configure the application for specific environments with corresponding configuration files in `config/environment`.

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <env name="APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT" value="testing" />
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Integration Tests">
            <directory>.</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Works fine for me.